# How to call DOS Interrupts within a C/C++ program using Inline Assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, dos, interrupt

I need to call some DOS interrupts (Services) from a C/C++ program, I tried the following inline asm code: 
(Read a character)

```
int main()
{
asm(
 "movb $0x01, %ah;"
 "int $0x21"
 );
system("PAUSE");
}
```

But it did not work ! I would like to know what have i done wrong here ! Also if there is another way to call dos interrupts !
Thank You !

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it did not work?" Did it compile? Did it crash? Did it run, but not have the desired effect?

Comment: My understanding of INT 21h function 01h is that it should read a character from standard input (blocking until one is available) and return it in the AL register.

Comment: Sorry for the missing details !
I'm using Code Blocks as IDE (so the compiler is GCC ), This code compiles fine, but on execution it generates an error after a second or two, with code:0xc0000005,
My platform is Windows XP on intel x86,
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only use DOS interrupts from DOS programs, so to make this work, you'd need a really ancient C++ compiler like Visual C++ 1.0 or 1.5, or Turbo C++/Borland C++ up through something like 4.5 or possibly 5.0. Then you'd have to fix your assembly code -- what you've written looks like AT&T syntax, but all the DOS compilers of which I'm aware use Intel syntax. There is one semi-exception to that: djgcc. This an ancient version of gcc that runs under a DOS extender, so it uses AT&T syntax, and still supports a set of DOS-like interrupts (though you're really using the DOS extender, not DOS per se).

Even then, the program would only run on a system that supports DOS programs (and Microsoft is quickly dropping that from windows -- e.g., it's absent in all the x64 versions of Windows).

DOS has been obsolete long enough that writing new code for it doesn't make sense. If you want to read a key like that, write a Windows program, and use something like [`ReadConsoleInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead.

Edit: Okay, if you really want to do this, the obvious way would be to pick a [DOS extender](http://www.thefreecountry.com/programming/dosextenders.shtml) and port a current version of gcc to it. The other possibility would be to pick a compiler like [OpenWatcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) or [Digital Mars](http://www.digitalmars.com/) that's still maintained and already ported to a [DOS extender](http://www.japheth.de/HX.html).

Comment: I still see new projects using FreeDOS (http://www.freedos.org/) from time to time. The last one I recall was for a control loader in a flight simulator.

Comment: @Judge Maygarden:I see lots of things I don't believe make any sense. In fairness, I suppose a DOS program could make sense under *limited* circumstances -- though offhand, about the only one I can think of is a hard real-time system that can't afford unpredictable timing of Windows. Even then, it's suspect though -- there are better RT/OSes than DOS.

Comment: This was a real-time system, but I admit I thought it was dumb when I saw it. Although, the "free" part of FreeDOS is attractive as opposed to something like VxWorks, RedHawk, LynxOS, etc.

Comment: Thank you sir, that was useful. As you may note I'm a student on computer science, and we need to understand these old systems ! But how can i do it on a modern compiler like the new GCC for example ?

Comment: @rockr90 as Jerry said DJGPP is a port of GCC (and other GNU tools) to MS-DOS but it works in 32-bit protected mode which is possibly not what you want. For writing 16-bit real mode apps you'll have to use a antique compiler.

Comment: @rockr90 In case all you want is to test snippets of DOS assembly code you could use an assembler instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may need an x86 emulator like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) to run this code under Windows XP.

Comment: Tried it ! But it does not run, instead a message is printed saying "This Program cannot run in dos mode" don't understand where is the problem ! 
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to build the code using the above mentioned obsolete compiler, THEN run it under DOSBox or an older OS.