# Assembly code (written for masm) in C program (compiled with gcc)... how?

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans, assembly, masm

I have assembly code and I want to implement it into a C program. I've been using masm to get my assembly code working, and I'm using gcc to compile C code.

I'm using NetBeans in Windows XP.

I want the command prompt to go fullscreen, then draw a line, like this does:

```
.model small
.stack

.code
    main proc far
    mov ax,@data
    mov DS,ax
    mov ah,00h
    mov al,12h
    int 10h 
    mov ah,02h
    mov dh,14 
    mov dl,37
    int 10h

    mov di,65
    mov ah,0ch
    mov bh,00h
    mov al,09h
    mov Cx,290
    mov dx,200

arriba: int 10h
    inc cx      
    dec di      
    Jnz arriba
    mov di,65
    mov ah,08h
    int 21h
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h 

    main endp
    end main
```

That code works if I use masm, but I don't know how to get it working inside my C program... thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call DOS Interrupts within a C/C++ program using Inline Assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716362/how-to-call-dos-interrupts-within-a-c-c-program-using-inline-assembly)

Comment: O.o!? So I would need to use turbo c or something like that to mess up with the console via assembler? omg... but then all of my C code will break, right? for example, I won't be able to use a MessageBox, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally mixing assembler with C can be done with GCC by defining functions written in asm in separate assembler file, which if compiled to .o and then linked together with C program, which calls the function that was in object compiled from assembler.

For that you need to know calling convention, how parameters are passed in stack or registers and write header which defines function prototype, which is implemented in assembler.

Some examples how to mix asm with C:

http://www.cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmexamples/

Other way would be to use GCC inline assembler syntax: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Note that originally GNU Assembler syntax is quite different than masm and many other x86 assemblers. However looks like this has been fixed in v. 2.10 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler)

Also @Neil's answer stands, you cannot do DOS Interrupts from windows program.

Comment: So, can I make an assembly code that opens its own command prompt where I can control anything DOS (like if I would've done it with assembly alone), then call to it from the main program?

Comment: If the assembler code above works in Windows XP command prompt, probably DOS interrupts are emulated there. 

Yes you can make main program in C and call your assembly code from there as a function. In answer I tried to give pointers how to combine your C and Assembler code.

Answer (score 4):

You can't mix DOS interrupts with the Windows API. You probably need to use DirectX's [full screen mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206358.aspx) instead.

Comment: But, and please correct me if I'm wrong, I wouldn't be able to use assembly code to do that, right?

Comment: @Kirby: it's possible to do in asm, but it's probably not as straightforward in Windows as in DOS (it appears that the DirectX functionality is accessible via COM interfaces).

Comment: This looks unnecessarily complicated for a final project, so I'm telling my teacher about it xD thank you very much!